# How do I select specific rows with an offset

Tags: mysql, database

So I have this table

```
id  |  gender  |  name
1   |  f       |  kate
2   |  m       |  john
3   |  f       |  monica
4   |  f       |  zoey
5   |  m       |  perry
6   |  f       |  mary
7   |  m       |  paul
8   |  f       |  carol
9   |  m       |  mark
10  |  m       |  ross
11  |  f       |  emily
12  |  m       |  Jay
13  |  m       |  Mike
```

If I did `SELECT id name FROM users WHERE gender = m`
I get this:

```
id  |  gender  |  name
2   |  m       |  john
5   |  m       |  perry
7   |  m       |  paul  <<<
9   |  m       |  mark  <<<
10  |  m       |  ross  <<<
12  |  m       |  Jay
13  |  m       |  Mike
```

---

This is what I want to do:

I want to do this because I have a website and I want to display 3 results on each page (so newest entries are shown first). So on **page 1** it should show

```
id  |  gender  |  name
13  |  m       |  Mike
12  |  m       |  Jay
10  |  m       |  ross
```

**page 2:**

```
id  |  gender  |  name
9   |  m       |  mark
7   |  m       |  paul  
5   |  m       |  perry
```

**page 3:**

```
id  |  gender  |  name
2   |  m       |  john
```

**Question: What select statement do I use to get the results of like in page 3**.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE gender = 'm'
LIMIT 6, 3
ORDER BY DESC
```

I think I'm right, but it doesn't work. To me, Limit `6` means, get the 6th result (in this case its John). Then the `3` means from the 6th result, get the 7th and 8th result. However, we don't have the 7th, 8th. So we should only get the 6th result, aka John.

Comment: Note that m <> 'm'. In consequence, your question is unclear - and you cannot simply make up syntax

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, forgot to put it (I was making up this example, forgot to put it). I edited my question, but how do I make a select statement to get the results I would on page 3

Comment: Did you try to put the LIMIT after the ORDER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OFFSET and LIMIT is not related with id, instead related with row_number.  Here is Fiddle for your understanding.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t
>     (`id` int, `gender` varchar(1), `name` varchar(6))
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO t
>     (`id`, `gender`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'f', 'kate'),
>     (2, 'm', 'john'),
>     (3, 'f', 'monica'),
>     (4, 'f', 'zoey'),
>     (5, 'm', 'perry'),
>     (6, 'f', 'mary'),
>     (7, 'm', 'paul'),
>     (8, 'f', 'carol'),
>     (9, 'm', 'mark'),
>     (10, 'm', 'ross'),
>     (11, 'f', 'emily'),
>     (12, 'm', 'Jay'),
>     (13, 'm', 'Mike')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t
> WHERE gender = 'm'
> ORDER BY ID DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | gender | name 
> -: | :----- | :----
> 13 | m      | Mike 
> 12 | m      | Jay  
> 10 | m      | ross 
>  9 | m      | mark 
>  7 | m      | paul 
>  5 | m      | perry
>  2 | m      | john
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM t
> WHERE gender = 'm'
> ORDER BY ID DESC
> LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3
> ```
>
> ```
> id | gender | name 
> -: | :----- | :----
>  9 | m      | mark 
>  7 | m      | paul 
>  5 | m      | perry
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec1dd07c0f715eaa563aacd33d21d135)*

---

For selecting Third page

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE gender = 'm'
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 6
```